# how to remove entry from hashmap by Value?

Tags: java, hashmap

I need a method to remove a entryset from hashmap by it's value. Is there a simple method without iteration?

Answer (score 28):

There's a simple method, but it'll use iteration internally.  (There's no way around that.)

```
map.values().remove(valueToRemove);
```

Comment: The OP mentionned the removal of an 'entryset'. If he meant a Set, then he can use map.values().removeAll(setOfValuesToRemove); 
@cataschok note that map.values.remove(valueToRemove) will only remove the first valueToRemove encountered.

Comment: map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(value));

Answer (score 8):

Not in HashMap but [google-guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) has a BiMap and you could do it like below pseudo-code

```
BiMap m=new HashBiMap();
m.inverse().remove(valueYouWantToRemove)
```

Comment: FYI, your link to the Guava Javadoc is out of date -- a better link would be [this](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap) or [this](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) -- and you'd instantiate something like a `HashBiMap`, since `BiMap` is an interface.  Additionally, this technique only works if you know your values are unique -- this wasn't clear from the OP's post.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thx for the comments. My intent was to just provide pseudo-code. Anyways I corrected it.