# Remove Key value pair from map of given object value in java

Tags: java

How to remove elements from Java map for a given object value.

**Sample Data:**

```
{
3cc612eqwdwc3-4dce-11e7-b4a2-fe984uyucc15272:[code=5
     user_key=dcfb5f5f-588e-11e6-85b9-fe984cc15272
     message=You have successfully logged in...
     roles_name=PLATFORM_ADMIN
     access_token=3cc612c3-4dce-11e7-b4a2-fe984cc15272
     user_id=superadmin
     utc_time=2017-06-10 11:16:23.0
     roles_id=7
     token_type=0
     access_key=d3cd4e3f-5946-11e6-9bb0-fe984cc15272
     status=true
     is_valid=null
     ]
3cc61fdfff2c3-4dce-11e7-b4atuy2-fe984cc15272:[code=5
     user_key=dcfb5f5f-588e-11e6-85b9-fe984cc15272
     message=You have successfully logged in...
     roles_name=PLATFORM_ADMIN
     access_token=3cc612c3-4dce-11e7-b4a2-fe984cc15272
     user_id=superadmin
     utc_time=2017-06-10 11:16:23.0
     roles_id=7
     token_type=0
     access_key=d3cd4e3f-5946-11e6-9bb0-fe984cc15272
     status=true
     is_valid=null
     ]
3cc612cddf3-4dce-11e7-b4a562-fe984cc15272:[code=5
     user_key=dcfb5f5f-5ddd88e-11e6-85b9-fe984cc15272
     message=You have successfully logged in...
     roles_name=PLATFORM_ADMIN
     access_token=3cc612c3-4dce-11e7-b4a2-fe984cc15272
     user_id=superadmin
     utc_time=2017-06-10 11:16:23.0
     roles_id=7
     token_type=0
     access_key=d3cd4e3f-5946-11e6-9bb0-fe984cc15272
     status=true
     is_valid=null
     ]
3cc6f12c3-4dce-11e7-b4oopa2d-fe984cc15272:[code=5
     user_key=dcfb5f5f-588e-11e6-85b9-fe984cc15272
     message=You have successfully logged in...
     roles_name=PLATFORM_ADMIN
     access_token=3cc612c3-4dce-11e7-b4a2-fe984cc15272
     user_id=superadmin1
     utc_time=2017-06-10 11:16:23.0
     roles_id=7
     token_type=0
     access_key=d3cd4e3f-5946-11e6-9bb0-fe984cc15272
     status=true
     is_valid=null
     ]
3cc61vc2c3-4dcdse-11ep[7-b4a2-fe984cc15272:[code=5
     user_key=dcfb5f5f-5ddd88e-11e6-85b9-fe984cc15272
     message=You have successfully logged in...
     roles_name=PLATFORM_ADMIN
     access_token=3cc612c3-4dce-11e7-b4a2-fe984cc15272
     user_id=superadmin1
     utc_time=2017-06-10 11:16:23.0
     roles_id=7
     token_type=0
     access_key=d3cd4e3f-5946-11e6-9bb0-fe984cc15272
     status=true
     is_valid=null
     ]
}
```

For above sample data, Is there any way to remove all map elements containing object value `user_key=dcfb5f5f-588e-11e6-85b9-fe984cc15272` without using loop or some other optimized way .

I have tried this by using `remove()` method but it only deletes using key.

Comment: Just loop through your map. It's the only way.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527565/how-to-remove-entry-from-hashmap-by-value

Comment: @dehasi : Thanks for the support. it works perfect for string key and string values. please help in deleting same for object values in map.

Comment: @AbhishekGinani Could you put some code? Which map do you use? Does your object implement equals and hashcode?

Answer (score 0):

Well, possibly I'm not correct. But it seems that you can't remove by key or value. I suggest to use filtering instead. Java8 based pseudo code:

```
Map<Key, Value> filteredMap = map.entrySet()
.stream()
.filter(e -> !e.getValue().getUserKey().equals("dcfb5f5f-588e-11e6-85b9-fe984cc15272"))
.collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```